# GoogleMapReact : Next.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChildren')

Tags: typescript, next.js, google-map-react

I'm developing a basic nextjs app with the google-map-react component and nextjs. I got the following error every time I try to use the  component

*TypeError: can't access property "getChildren", n.props.dispatcher is undefined*

Idk what to do .. it seem to be an issue with my current reactapp version

```
    import React from 'react';
    import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

    export default function Map({ coords }: { coords: { lat: number; lng: number } }) {

    return (
        <>
        <div className='w-full h-4/5'>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLkeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
                defaultCenter={coords}
                center={coords}
                defaultZoom={14}
                margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
            >
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
        <div>
            dede
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "travelcompagnon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.10.2",
    "@types/node": "17.0.31",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.10",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you would need to disable reactStrictMode and restart your next app server

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```